# Change color of vertex outline in tkz-graph

Tags: color, diagrams, tkz-graph

Suppose I have the following graph:

```
 \documentclass[]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{fullpage}
 \usepackage[upright]{fourier}
 \usepackage{tkz-graph}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{document}
 \SetVertexNormal[Shape      = circle,
             LineWidth  = 1pt]
  \SetUpEdge[lw         = 1pt,
       color      = black,
       labelcolor = white,
     labelstyle = {sloped,text=black}]

 \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \Vertex[x=0 ,y=0]{A}
  \Vertex[x=3 ,y=3]{B}
  \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->}}
  \Edge[label = $1$](A)(B)
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

I know how to change the vertex fill color and the vertex text color, but I'd like to be able to change the color of the actual outline of the vertex--i.e., the vertices in this code should have a red outline. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the option `LineColor=red` in `\SetVertexNormal` command.